# What should I do if some important URLs are missing from my sitemap in Rank Math?

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap, google-search-console

Some of my product URLs aren't showing up on the sitemap. I've checked that they're not set to noindex, and I've cleared my site cache. I've also reviewed my Rank Math settings, but I still haven't been able to solve the issue. What should I do?

I've tried several things to resolve the issue of missing product URLs from my sitemap in Rank Math. First, I checked that the affected pages were not set to noindex and cleared my site cache, but this did not solve the problem. Next, I reviewed my Rank Math settings and made sure that all relevant post types and taxonomies were selected for inclusion in the sitemap. However, even after these efforts, some URLs were still missing from my sitemap.

I was expecting to see all of my product URLs included in the sitemap generated by Rank Math, so that search engines could properly crawl and index them. However, despite my efforts, some important URLs remained missing from the sitemap.

At this point, I'm unsure what else to try to resolve the issue. I would appreciate any suggestions or advice on how to ensure that all of my product URLs are included in the sitemap generated